# Can single hash be used to arrange data?

Tags: string, sorting, hash

I am trying to know if a single hash say MD5, SHA256 be used to arrange data in an order.
For example, I have a file with data in a random order (1 alphabet per line):

```
a
z
p
l
m
g
```

Now i hash the file and get :gdgshadgxf239838g9x..etc

And, after I short it, I get;

```
a
g
l
m
p
z
```

Hash :37hsgd7y3hgsd83b...etc

Can I revert back to the order of original file with just the 2 hashes and sorted order of alphabets?

Comment: You could only do this via brute-force search: you'd have to enumerate every possible ordering of the lines (720 of them, for 6 lines) to see which one produces the original hash.  Any hash function that allowed a shortcut here would be too broken for anyone to use in the first place.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the help. And can the chance of collision be reduced with muliple hashes of different types ?

Comment: A collision is an *extremely* unlikely occurrence here - but if you must worry about it, choosing a more recent hash algorithm (with more bits in its output) would likely be a simpler and more efficient solution than using multiple older hashes.